# How to stop Xcode from closing when opened from Xamarin Studio

Tags: xcode5, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm working in Xamarin Studio. Sometimes I need to launch Xcode to use its interface builder. The problem is whenever I go back to Xamarin Studio, Xcode closes. This means I have to relaunch Xcode every time I want to make an edit to a xib file. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour was changed in/around November time (after this question was asked) so this should not be happening anymore. Please get in touch if you are still seeing this happen.

Answer (score 2):

You won't like this, but the answer is no. The reasoning behind this is simple. Everytime Xamarin needs to launch the Interface Builder, it creates a "proxy" project containing the relevant `.xib` files and headers. The idea is that once you completed your changes, which may e.g. also involve adding Outlets to headers, Xamarin Studio reads back the proxy project and synchronizes any changes to the `.Designer.cs` files.

As an alternative to using Xcode's IB you can try using the new Designer integrated into Xamarin Studio (which can usually get the basics done).